# Formal port does not exist in entity

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I am getting this error while trying to implement a D flip-flop and simulate it:

> VRFC 10-718] formal port  does not exist in entity . 
>   Please compare the definition of block  to its component
>   declaration and its instantiation to detect the mismatch.

I am new to the language and can't figure out why this happening.

Bellow is my VHDL code.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
entity Interfata is
port(
 clk : in std_logic;
 data :in std_logic;
 Q : out std_logic;
 Qnot : out std_logic
);

end Interfata;

architecture Behavioral of Interfata is

component LATCH 
  port(
   set : in std_logic;
   reset : in std_logic;
   data : out std_logic;
   data_not : out std_logic
  );
end component;

signal latch_set: std_logic;
signal latch_reset:std_logic;
begin
  uut1: latch port map(
    set => latch_set,
    reset => latch_reset,
    data => Q,
    data_not => Qnot
);

process(clk,data)
begin
  if(clk' event and clk='1') then
    latch_set <= data;
    latch_reset <= not data;
  end if;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

here's the latch.vhd code

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;


entity latch is
port(
 set : in std_logic;
 reset :in std_logic;
 data : out std_logic;
 data_not : out std_logic

);
end latch;

architecture Behavioral of latch is
signal data_temp : std_logic:='0';
signal data_not_temp : std_logic:='1';
begin
  process(set, reset) begin
    data_temp <= not(reset or data_not_temp);
    data_not_temp <= not(set or data_temp);
    data <= data_temp;
    data_not <= data_not_temp;
  end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: What tool are you using? The process in `Interfata` contains too many signals in its sensitivity list, while the process in `latch` doesn't contain all needed signals in its sensitivity list.

Comment: I am using Vivado. I can't quite understand what do you mean by too many signals and that it doesn't contain all needed signals. Could you please elaborate? I know it probably sounds silly but I am still figuring out how vhdl works. Thanks!

Comment: I've compiled your description using Modelsim and it didn't complain. Try unchecking the incremental compilation option in the simulation settings [[1](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Simulation-and-Verification/Formal-port-does-not-exist-in-entity/td-p/893642)].

Comment: It worked,, thank you!

Comment: While this code will show some behavior in simulation, it will never work in a Xilinx FPGA.